# Update field in table using SUM of the same field in a specific date interval

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-update, dateinterval

I have the following table in SQL Server:

[image: Sales]

**Business rule** that must be applied to table: if a `Staff_Id` reaches `Staff_Sales` of 2500+ for the past 6 months, the sales quota is reached (..and thus `QuotaReached = 1`).

In short, I need to `UPDATE` the column `Staff_Sales_Last_6_Months`. This column must be calculated, so that we get a result like this:

[image: SalesUpdated]

Notice how the last row has calculated the SUM of `Staff_Sales` for the past 6 months. This is exactly what I need.

My attempt (which does not work):

```
WITH cte_SumSales AS
(
    SELECT
        Staff_Id, SUM(Sales) AS SumSales
    FROM 
        Sales
    WHERE 
        [Date] BETWEEN [Date] AND DATEADD(month, -6, [Date])
    GROUP BY 
        Staff_Id
)
UPDATE t1
SET t1.Staff_Sales_Last_6_Months = t2.SumSales
FROM Sales AS t1
INNER JOIN cte_SumSales AS t2 ON T1.Staff_Id = T2.Staff_Id
```

Any ideas on how I can fix this / better approaches?

Thanks.

Comment: What about an indexed view of the best answer below?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
UPDATE te
SET Staff_Sales_Last_6_Month = SS
    , QuotaReached = IIF(SS < 3000, 0, 1)
FROM Table1 as te
OUTER APPLY (
    SELECT SUM(ti.Staff_Sales) 
    FROM Table1 as ti
    WHERE te.Staff_Id = ti.Staff_Id 
        and ti.Date1 <= te.Date1
        and ti.Date1 >= DATEADD(MONTH,-6,te.Date1)
) as ta(SS);
```